# Scrape Twitter for hashtag containing word instead of exact match

Tags: twitter, match, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using Tweepy to scrape twitter. I've been looking through the Streaming API and under "track" it shows the possible returns when searching a tweet for text.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters

For the most part it seems the API will only return exact matches, (and some extra cases with punctuality directly following or prefacing) I'm searching for tweets with `#` and  in the following hashtag a certain word, e.g. `pillow`. So for this example, tweets I would like:

`#pillow`
`#mybedpillow`
`#mypillowbed`

But if I use the API tracking `#pillow` I will only get the exact match with `#pillow`

If I do `pillow` I will get tweets with `#pillow` but no text following.

The only approach I see as of now is to stream random tweets and then filter them out for the hashtags that match my case. This will take me much longer to gather the data I require. Any thoughts?